# How do I prepopulate from a previous object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this line of code

```
Account.build_address
```

and this works but I need to prepopulate is with a previous address so if i had the params i could do

```
Account.build_address(params[:address])
```

But i dont have the params I have a previous address object so for the sake of example i can say

```
@previous_address = Address.first
Account.build_address(@previous_address)
```

But I dont think this is in the format i need to prepopulate...any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@previous_address = Address.first
Address.build_address(@address.attributes)
```

`@address.attributes` returns a hash of the object's ActiveRecord attributes... so as long as build_address expects a hash, it should generate an object equivalent to the address you pass in.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build, you can just clone the existing object:

```
@previous_address.clone
```

That will copy all columns of the `@previous_address` model, except for the `id` field